# Matplotlib multiple imshow share an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am plotting 5 imshows one after the other as shown below.
[image]

I use the below code to generate the above plot.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(511) 
ax2 = plt.subplot(512)
ax3 = plt.subplot(513)
ax4 = plt.subplot(514)
ax5 = plt.subplot(515)
ax1.imshow(data1)
ax2.imshow(data2)
ax3.imshow(data3)
ax4.imshow(data4)
ax5.imshow(data5)
plt.show()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make all the imshows share the x axis (and plt them right one below the other without white gaps)

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily remove the xticks and labels from the axis and reduce the padding but you will still need some space between the images or the y axis ticks labels will overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing between subplots can be changed using `subplots_adjust` method. More can be found in [official documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

Here is an example of removing the vertical space between two subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.125,
                    bottom=0.1,
                    right=0.9,
                    top=0.9,
                    wspace=0.2,
                    hspace=0)

x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)

y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o-')
plt.title('A tale of 2 subplots')
plt.ylabel('Damped oscillation')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x2, y2, '.-')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Undamped')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output of two subplots without vertical space]

Comment: There is one major flaw with that approach alone: in your example, `x1` and `x2` are different, but there is no way to tell that from looking at the graph! Using the `sharex` argument of `plt.subplots` adresses this problem, as per my answer

Comment: @gazoh, this is a demonstration of `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust` method. In OP's question the X axis is same for all subplots.

Comment: is the X-axis really the same for all subplt, and will they always be? My point is both `sharex` and `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust ` should be used, IMO

Comment: The main problem is that `hspace` will not help for default `imshow` plots where the spacing is determined by the aspect of the image. There are enough other questions and answers on that subject though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to arsho's answer, you can also make different subplots share axes, using the arguments `share` and/or `sharey` chen creating the subplot.

Something like this should work for you:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(511) 
ax2 = plt.subplot(512, sharex = ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(513, sharex = ax1)
ax4 = plt.subplot(514, sharex = ax1)
ax5 = plt.subplot(515, sharex = ax1)
ax1.imshow(data1)
ax2.imshow(data2)
ax3.imshow(data3)
ax4.imshow(data4)
ax5.imshow(data5)
plt.show()
```